# Command: [ -z "" ] && echo 0 || echo 1

Tags: shell

Running `[ -z "" ] && echo 0 || echo 1` gives output `0`. What is this command? How is it interpreted?

Comment: Where did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

In bash (and similar shells), `[ x ] && y || z` is an idiomatic short-hand way of writing `if [ x ] ; then y ; else z ; fi`, when `y` is a simple statement that won't/can't evaluate to `false`.   It's useful when you don't want to waste 5 lines of valuable screen/editor vertical space for a simple test.

By "idiomatic", I mean that it's a common shell programming practice.  One that takes advantage of the way that logical AND (`&&`) and OR (`||`) work in the shell.  `y` is executed if `x` is true.  `z` is executed if `x` is false...the catch is that `z` is **also** executed if `x` is true and `y` runs but evaluates to false (i.e. returns a non-zero exit code) - this is why it should **not** be used if there is any chance of that occurring.   e.g. `[ -z "" ] && false || echo 1` outputs "1", even though the condition `-z ""` is true.

In other words, it's (almost) equivalent to:

```
if [ -z "" ] ; then
  echo 0
else
  echo 1
fi
```

This full-form `if; then ... ; else ... ; fi` construct does not have the same flaw that the short-hand form does.  This construct is correct and always works, while the short-hand is a quick-and-dirty hack that's useful in some limited circumstances.

`-z` tests whether a string is is empty.

That command is, in English:

> If the empty string is empty then display "0", otherwise display "1".

It will always display "0".

Comment: true, but it's typically only used when both `y` and `z` are simple statements that won't evaluate to false - echoing a string, setting a variable, and the like.   anything more complex than that needs a proper `if/then/else/fi`.

Comment: You can write `if [ -z "$var" ] ; then echo 0; else echo 1 ; fi` on one line if you want, it's not about using lines. Or just say `[ -z "$var" ]; echo $?` in this case.

Comment: well, yes, of course.  but this question was about `[ -z "" ] && echo 0 || echo 1`.  and it's more typing.  btw, for me it IS about not wasting vertical screen space AND less typing.  I know it's "wrong'. I also know it's harmless in the contexts that I use it.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't concerned about that being "wrong", just that it's possible to put the `if ... then` in a smaller space too. But of course, it's a bit more verbose, so there's that tradeoff.